# In gsheets how do I pull data from multiple sheets within the workbook in a query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is what I have so far. It worked fine before adding in the BinCounts ref.

```
=query(
{'Aggregated Data'!A2:G , BinCounts!A2:G}, "SELECT A, B, C, E, DAY(B), YEAR(B)" & if(COUNTBLANK(Sheet14!A1:A4)=4,""," WHERE " & TEXTJOIN(" AND ", True, Sheet14!A1:A4) & "WHERE Col1 <>"),1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use <kbd>;</kbd> instead of <kbd>,</kbd> in between multiple sheets.

Query should look like this:

`=query( {'Aggregated Data'!A2:G; BinCounts!A2:G}, "SELECT A, B, C, E, DAY(B), YEAR(B)" & if(COUNTBLANK(Sheet14!A1:A4)=4,""," WHERE " & TEXTJOIN(" AND ", True, Sheet14!A1:A4) & "WHERE Col1 <>"),1)`

Sample query that queries multiple sheets.

[image: sample query]

**Reference:**

- [Query multiple sheets](https://codingisforlosers.com/google-sheets-query-function/#4_How_to_Query_multiple_Sheets_ranges_at_the_same_time)